# What is the right thing to install: open-vm-tools or vmware binary?

Tags: rhel, vmware, vmware-workstation

We have machines running Red Hat Enterprise Linux version 7.x.
We are not sure what is the best thing to do with regards to VMware support.

**We have two options**

1. install `open-vm-tools`  (from Red Hat)

or

2. install VMware binary packages from VMware

Comment: You definitely need the `open-vm-tools`.

Comment: [VMware support policy](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`open-vm-tools` is developed by VMware, see [their GitHub page](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools) for details. That page provides [the following answer](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools#will-there-be-continued-support-for-vmware-tools-and-osp) to your question:

> It is recommended that open-vm-tools be used for the Linux distributions where open-vm-tools is available. VMware will not provide OSPs for operating systems where open-vm-tools is available.

So you should install `open-vm-tools` rather than the binary packages provided by VMware.

[This Red Hat customer portal page](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1694373) is also relevant (but you need a portal account to view it). See also [this VMware knowledgebase article on the topic](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803), which says `open-vm-tools` ...

> Eliminates the need to separately install VMware Tools when open-vm-tools is bundled with the operating system because open-vm-tools is a fully-supported open source implementation of VMware Tools.

Comment: btw - I find the open-vm-tools as part of redhat repo , so I if this pkg is under VM-ware responsibility then why red-hat take care about it? , I mean why this pkg not under VM-ware responsibility ?

Comment: I think VMware forked it.

Comment: sorry but what you mean - forked it. ?

Comment: No, it's not forked. The RHEL package is hosted by Red Hat, like all official RHEL packages. The VMware GitHub page hosts the “upstream” code (used in all distributions), Red Hat hosts RHEL-specific packaging.